# Align Empty to center of face (2.8)

Tags: snapping

I try to snap a Empty to a face.
I turned snapping on with the following settings:
[image]

Here is a video of what is happening (including holding the control key)
[image]

How can I snap a empty to the center of a surface?

Comment: I'm using snap cursor to selected (Shift+S menu), then selection to cursor. I made hotkeys for them on my mouse. But maybe someone knows a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the [3d Cursor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/3d_cursor.html), that's a pretty good use case and only takes *2 seconds*.  Select all relevant polygons, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, choose *Cursor to Selected* and create your *Empty* (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>...).